# Flutter, ClientSocketException: Connection Timed out

Tags: android, laravel, flutter, dart, connection-timeout

I am working an a flutter app with laravel API as backend. I getting an:

> ClientSocketException : Connection Timed Out

api.dart

```
class Network {
  final String _url = 'http://192.168.0.143:8000/api';
  var token;

  _getToken() async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    token = jsonDecode(localStorage.getString('token') ?? '')['token'];
  }

  auth(filePath, data, apiURL) async {

    var fullUrl = _url + apiURL;
    return await http.post(
      Uri.parse(fullUrl),
      body: jsonEncode(data),
      headers: _setHeaders()
    );
  }

  getData(apiURL) async {
    var fullUrl = _url + apiURL;
    await _getToken();
    return await http.get(
      Uri.parse(fullUrl),
      headers: _setHeaders(),
    );
  }

  _setHeaders() => {
        // 'Content-type': 'application/json',
        // 'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      };
}
```

login.dart

```
void _login() async {
    var data = {'username': username, 'phoneNumber': phoneNumber};
    var res;
    try {
      res= await Network().auth(profileImage?.path ?? '', data, '/loginOrRegister');
      // var body = json.decode(res);
      var body = await res.stream.toBytes();
      // body = String.fromCharCodes(body);
      // print('body $body');
      // if (body['success']) {
      //   SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      //   localStorage.setString('token', json.encode(body['token']));
      //   localStorage.setString('user', json.encode(body['user']));
      //   Navigator.pushReplacement(
      //     context,
      //     new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
      //   );
      // } else {
      //   _showMsg(body['message']);
      // }
    } on SocketException { 
        print("Socket exception: ${e.toString()}");
    }catch (e) {
      print('Failed to create user: $e');
    }
  }
```

I read many related questions to this, and I tried these but it still not working:

- I added internet permission to `AndroidManifest <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`
- I use my PC address IP, and make the physical mobile device and the PC to be on the same WiFi

If it can help, I try to access laravel app from the Chrome of my phone by using http://pc-ip-address but getting PC-IP-address take a lot of time to answer, ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

**UPDATED**
I disabled the windows defender firewall and getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Are you using docker? what are you using to serve `8000` as your web port? you need to add more info, does `localhost:8000` on the local machine work?

Comment: I am using Laravel as backend, and Laravel are served on localhost:8000 by default. For more information Apache as server, and PHP download with MAMP